# Can we have multiple versions of the same application available to different groups in Google Play?

Tags: android, deployment, google-play, testflight

I have a question regarding Google Play Alpha Testing apps:

Is it possible to have different versions of the same app available at the same time?

My requirement is to make the stable version (Let's say 1.0) available to Testers and the latest release (Let's say 1.1) available to the developers. When I uploaded the latest version Google Play is automatically archiving the previous version.

This was possible with `TestFlight` but as `TestFlight` is removing their support for Android I'm considering alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can keep different version of same app in Google Play.If you update an app previous one is deleted automatically to control the amount of  app Google play.
If different versions of same app is available how much hectic will it be for users as well as for Google to manage so many apps.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, TestFlight does it efficiently without any hiccups. We used to target different versions of the app to different sets of users. Its a shame that TestFlight is discontinuing Android support.